# Scrollbar appears when a dialog is opened

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having kind of a weird issue when opening any dialog in Angular:
An vertical scrollbar appears with no trail.
I really open the dialog with a fixed width.

*component.ts*

```
const dialog = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '80%',
      maxWidth: '80%',
      disableClose: true,
      autoFocus: false
});
```

Any container in this component is set to have a height, but they don't overflow in any case.

*dialog.html*

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title class="title">{{ 'title' | translate }}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content class="content">
    <!-- Some content here... -->
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions class="actions">
    <button mat-button (click)="cancel()">{{ 'cancel' | translate }}</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="confirm()">{{ 'confirm' | translate }}</button>
</div>
```

If matters, this is the style sheet of the dialog (non related)

*dialog-style.scss*

```
.actions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And here is a snapshot of the appearing scrollbar.

[annoying-vertical-scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQYVB.png)

I can provide some code left. I don't know where it comes from.
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `overflow-y: hidden;` to `.actions` css (assuming the element with class `.action` contains the scrollbar.)

Comment: Scroll is not appearing because of actions container.
It appears all over the page (check the pic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed hiding overflow into the container (inside the component) where the dialog was opening.
Not the dialog itself, nor the main body container.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
.content {
   overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
   overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}
```